# Unable to register service with pointer to sample struct

Tags: go, grpc

When trying to reference the struct as a pointer. It will result in literals being unable to be passed in to register the service.

I believe this may be due to how grpc has changed from different versions, as I was able to get it working this way prior... But installing a fresh version of grpc has resulted in it not working.

I've tried to create a new struct. But you will get a memory address violation. I've also tried to pass in the actual struct itself with no luck.

The source

```golang
package rpc

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"

    "atomic-swaps/src/api"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

// ApiServer : Empty API server struct
type ApiServer struct{}

// Server : The Server endpoint response
func (s *ApiServer) Server(ctx context.Context, message api.ServerMessage) (*api.ServerMessage, error) {
    ping := "pong"
    time := int64(time.Now().Unix())
    return &api.ServerMessage{ping, time, struct{}{}, nil, 128}, nil
}

// StartGRPCServer : Starts a fresh GRPC Server on TCP
func StartGRPCServer(port string) {
    tcp, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error starting GRPC Server: %v", err)
    }

    server := grpc.NewServer()
    api.RegisterApiServer(server, &ApiServer{})

    fmt.Println("Starting gRPC server on " + port)
    server.Serve(tcp)
}
```

The error

```golang
src/rpc/grpc.go:33:32: cannot use &ApiServer literal (type *ApiServer) as type api.ApiServer in argument to api.RegisterApiServer:
    *ApiServer does not implement api.ApiServer (wrong type for Server method)
        have Server(context.Context, api.ServerMessage) (*api.ServerMessage, error)
        want Server(context.Context, *api.ServerMessage) (*api.ServerMessage, error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay... My bad guys...
It was actually a pointer error.

I forgot a pointer

```golang
func (s *ApiServer) Server(ctx context.Context, message api.ServerMessage) (*api.ServerMessage, error)
```

Needed to be

```golang
func (s *ApiServer) Server(ctx context.Context, message *api.ServerMessage) (*api.ServerMessage, error)
```